# openerp 7 one2many and many2one

Tags: python, xml, one-to-many, odoo, many-to-one

please refer below code lines between 205 - 280

https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp/blob/openerp/model%20class

and in my view xml lines between 255 - 337

https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp/blob/openerp/view.xml

and need to clarify where is my error.see in tea worker line

http://flic.kr/p/e6uf1E

loaded incorrect data from that drop down & its not need to me

@@senthilnathang:

you mean remove below line (line 283) ?

```
<field name='selected_tea_workers_line_ids' nolabel='1'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are adding parent (tea_worker_line_id 'bpl.offer') in child (selected_tea_workers_line_ids 'bpl.selected.tea.workers.line'), it is not needed remove it from the view coz you already made tea.worker.lines as one2many of bpl.offer .

Comment: yes remove it for reference please check sale module try to understand  sale module code so that you can reuse it in many places for your custom module

Comment: thanks
i change my code as follows..now its not showing & seems its not harm to my output  :-)
<field name='tea_line_worker_id' invisible="1" />